# Why animation didn't work if I put more than 4 items in menu push left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Was trying to put a left push menu on my site, but when I try to add more than 4 sidebar-item they just don't follow the animation. Otherwise the last item follow, so how can i fix it?

> Click Run code and Full page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Left Push Menu</title>
<style>
/*@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=roboto); */
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}
h1 { text-align:center; margin:50px auto; color:#fff;}

main {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2D3142;
  -webkit-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #008e00;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.nav-left{
  position: fixed;
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

.nav-right.visible-xs { z-index: 3; }

.hidden-xs { display: none; }

.middle { margin: 0 auto; }
 /*nada*/
.bar {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}
 /*nada*/
.nav-right.visible-xs .active .bar {
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}
 /*nada*/
.button.active .top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
}
 /*nada*/
.button.active .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}
/*nada*/
.button.active .middle { width: 0; }

.move-to-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(400px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(400px);
  -o-transform: translateX(400px);
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

nav { padding-top: 30px; }

.sidebar-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-item {
  margin: 30px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
/*-webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px);*/
.sidebar-item:first-child {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:last-child {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.sidebar-anchor {
  color: #008E00;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.sidebar-anchor:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008e00;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-anchor:hover:before { width: 100%; }

 @media (min-width: 480px) {

.nav-list { display: block; }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {

.nav-right { position: absolute; }

.hidden-xs { display: block; }

.visible-xs { display: none; }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--<div class="nav-left visible-xs">
  <div class="button" id="btn">
    <div class="bar top"></div>
    <div class="bar middle"></div>
    <div class="bar bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>-->
<!-- nav-right -->
<main>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-left hidden-xs">
      <div class="button" id="btn">
        <div class="bar top"></div>
        <div class="bar middle"></div>
        <div class="bar bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- nav-right --> 
  </nav>
  <h1>Left Push Menu</h1>
  <div class="jquery-script-ads" align="center">
</div>
</main>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-list">
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Consumption</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Historic</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">About</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">About</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">About</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleSidebar() {
    $(".button").toggleClass("active");
    $("main").toggleClass("move-to-right");
    $(".sidebar-item").toggleClass("active");
  }

  $(".button").on("click tap", function() {
    toggleSidebar();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      toggleSidebar();   
    }
  });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just applied only for 1st,2nd, 3rd and the last element in the css styling.

```
.sidebar-item {
  margin: 30px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px);
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Just add the above remove the others

Answer (score 0):

The transition styling explicitly applies to only the following "child" elements:

```
.sidebar-item:first-child {
  /*...*/
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(2) {
  /*...*/
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(3) {
  /*...*/
}

.sidebar-item:last-child {
  /*...*/
}
```

So if there's, say an `nth-child(4)`, and `nth-child(5)`, and so on then those don't have any transitions applied to them.

Add them:

```
.sidebar-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
}

/* and so on, changing values as necessary... */
```